# Several dropping areas for drag and drop example in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have the following example of dragging and dropping images in jQuery. This is nicely working (thanks!).

My next question is...how can I have, for example, 10 different dropping areas instead of just one but maintaining the same functionality?

I thought I could copy&paste 10 times the drop function, but for sure it is not a good practice. Should I also have 10 div id drop (i.e. div id="drop1", div id="drop2"...)?

Any help, please?

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".draggable").draggable({
            cursor: "crosshair",
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: 'clone'
      });

         $("#drop").droppable({ accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $("#drop").empty();
            var check = 0;
            // $( "#test" ).droppable( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {check = 1;} );

            var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
            elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
            var droppable = $(this);
            console.log("drop");
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);

            console.log($(this).attr('class'));

            if(!elementMouseIsOver.classList.contains("clone")) {
                console.log("no clone");
                $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo("#origin");
                // dropped.clone().appendTo(droppedOn);
                var clone = dropped.clone().addClass("clone");
                //clone[0].id = 'test';
                clone.appendTo(droppedOn);
            }
        },
        over: function(event, elem) {
            $(this).addClass("over");
            console.log("over");
        },
        out: function(event, elem) {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
        }
    });
      $("#drop").sortable();

      $("#origin").droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("drop");
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
      }});
});
</script>

    <title>Drag N Drop</title>
<style>
#origin
{
  /* background-color: lightgreen; */
  position: relative;
}

#drop {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.over {
  border: solid 5px purple;
}


</style>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="origin" class="fbox">
        <?php

        $sql2 = "SELECT *
                FROM players
                LIMIT 10";

        $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);

        $cont1 = 0;

        while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $res2 ) ) 
        {

            $cont1++;
?>


            <img id="<?php echo $row2["id"];?>" class="draggable" src="images/players/<?php echo $row2["name"]; ?>.png" width="50" height="50">



<?php

        }

?>
        </div>

        <div id="drop" class="fbox"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You could try to switch from `id`s to `class`es. Replace `$("#drop")` with `$(".drop")` and change `<div id="drop" class="fbox"></div>` to `<div class="drop fbox"></div>`. If that works, try to duplicate `<div class="drop fbox"></div>` ten times. No guarantee though

Comment: hi @kerbholz thanks a lot for your reply. I made the changes and now I have 2 dropping areas (I tried only with two). I can drag and drop images in both of them but, when I drop in any of them, the other gets empty. Is a step forward but what I really want is that every dropping area is independent from the rest, that is it can have its own image and can be replaced by any image without emptying the rest of dropping areas. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Not a Javascript expert, but `$("#drop").empty();` sounds like it empties/clears the specific container. If you changed that to `$(".drop").empty();` _all_ elements with class `drop` get cleared. I'd guess you need to change that to only clear the element that has been dropped on.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did. I replaced every instance of #drop by .drop and the output I get is the one I described before.